# Need a SQL insert query for a table from a temporary table without duplication

Tags: sql

I need to insert into a table from a temporary table without duplicating the data from temp table. ie , for each customer need to insert a single row with `SpecialCreditNoteAwarded`

My temporary table:

```
CustID  SalesMasterID   SpecialCreditNoteAwarded
------------------------------------------------
100       13139                92115
100       13148                92115
100       13150                92115
101       13204                 1175
101       13205                 1175
102       13209                  650
102       13210                  650
102       13211                  650
```

Result table

```
CustID  SaleID  SpecialCreditNoteAwarded
-----------------------------------------
100       0         92115
101       0          1175
102       0           650
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP BY` function in a `SELECT` statement to remove duplicates

```
 INSERT INTO Table_rslt (CustID, SaleID, SpecialCreditNoteAwarded)
   SELECT 
        CustID
        ,0
        ,SpecialCreditNoteAwarded
   FROM #temp
   GROUP BY CustID,SpecialCreditNoteAwarded;
```

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this answer is for `SQL SERVER`.

Comment: Using MSSQL , tried with above but inserting 8 rows into result table

Comment: Perhaps there might be leading/trailing white spaces in your columns, what are the data types for the 3 columns in your temp table ?also, try the update query

Comment: int , int, money , i have no updation in result table only insert     , tried with LTRIM(RTRIM( but same 8 row inserting into result table

Comment: Please create a fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/) for this, include the DDLs for the temp table

Comment: working fine .. Insert statement will work without group by Thanks @Midhun Joy